# How to get array with clear data from Active Record query without using map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I would like to ask if its possible get array with clear data from ActiveRecord query without using map, collect or each.

```
names = User.find(:all, :select => "name")
return names == [#<User name:"Peter">,#<User name:"Martin">]
```

and I want names == ["Peter", "Martin"] without using map, collect or each. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: just curious why you need it?

Comment: i just wonder if something like that exist. Also if i have a huge database i dont know if using map is now too slow.

Comment: Ruby is fast, I wouldn't worry about looping over a large dataset (unless you do it a lot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.connection.select_values("SELECT name FROM users")
#=> ["francois"]
```

Comment: I stand corrected that ActiveRecord doesn't provide such a method. But it does use map internally as I said.

Comment: Yes it is in ActiveRecord in rails 2. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#M001421

Answer (score 1):

Even if ActiveRecord provided a method to do what you want (single column to array of values), it would internally use a loop (each or collect) to do it.

I don't see what is so wrong with using a loop in this case, Ruby makes it quite easy to do it.

```
users = User.find(:all, :select => "name").collect { |u| u.name }
```

Comment: i think question clearly mentioned "without using map, collect or each"

Comment: Yes but it not possible to do it without looping. So I offered the most succinct solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that w/o using map, collect each ... etc......

In otherwords you can't get result like this in a single query.